# Accessing `chrome.send()` method in chrome web browser out of chrome's internal pages

Tags: google-chrome

I was wondering whether it's possible to use `chrome.send()` function ,which is accessible in chrome internal pages like `chrome://version`, for sending commands such as `chrome.send('restartBrowser')` to chrome browser outside of chrome internal pages and inside of my own custom web page or not.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you cannot do this in any normal web page. You would need to create your own internal pages by creating a custom [WebUI](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/webui) in order to utilize it.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks for the answer, the question came to me after 
reading another question in stack overflow, the solution was dependent on chrome.send() function. I couldn't find any solution online so I thought maybe someone else knows a way here. Apparently you are right, it's not possible in normal chrome.